# Duplication of arraylist in angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am copying data in two arrays this.contactOptions and this.updatedContactOptions, but when i modify this.contactOptions it is modifying this.updatedContactOptions as well, please help me understand why it is makaing changes in other array even though i am not updaing it?

here is the component file

```
export class JobListComponent implements OnInit {

  private contactOptions: Array<any> = [];
  private updatedContactOptions: Array<any> = [];


  private jobFormData: any = {

    "contactDetails": [],

  };
  private jobFormDataOriginal: any;
  private jobDTOptions: any = {};

  private isUnknownError: boolean = false;
  private errorHtml: string;

  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef, private utility: Utility) {


    this.jobForm = this.formBuilder.group({

      'contactDetails': [],
      'tags': [],
      'dispatchJob': true

      });


  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    let self = this;

    this.getWorkflow();
    this.getContacts();
  }

  clone(object: any) {
    return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(object));
  }



  setFormData(data,contactOptions) {
    let self = this;


    if (!data['endLocation']) {
      data['endLocation'] = {
        "address": '',
        "latitude": '',
        "longitude": ''
      }
    }
    this.jobFormData = this.clone(data);
    if (data.workflow) {
      this.jobFormData.workflowId = data.workflow.id;
    }
    if (data.assignee) {
      this.jobFormData.assigneeId = data.assignee && data.assignee.userId ? data.assignee.userId : null;
      this.jobForm.get('assignee.user').setValue('user');
      this.assigneeType = 'user';
    } 
    this.jobFormData.contactDetails = [];
    if (data.contacts != null) {
      var isDel=[];
      for (let j = 0; j < data.contacts.length; j++) {

        if(data.contacts[j].deleted){


          isDel.push({
            value: data.contacts[j].id,
            label: data.contacts[j].firstName + " " + data.contacts[j].lastName,
            disabled:data.contacts[j].deleted
          });
      }

      if(isDel.length>0){
        this.contactOptions[this.contactOptions.length]=this.clone(isDel[0]);
      }

        this.jobFormData.contactDetails=[...data.contacts[j].id];
        //this.jobFormData.contactDetails = [...this.jobFormData.contactDetails];
      }
    }
    this.jobFormData.tags = [];
    if (data.contacts != null) {
      for (let i = 0; i < data.tags.length; i++) {
        this.jobFormData.tags[i] = data.tags[i].tagId;
      }
      this.jobFormData.startDateTimeInDate = moment(data.scheduledStartTime).tz(self.timeZone).format(this.utility.DATEFORMAT_CALENDER[self.dateTimeFormat]);

    this.jobFormData.endDateTimeInDate = moment(data.estimatedEndTime).tz(self.timeZone).format(this.utility.DATEFORMAT_CALENDER[self.dateTimeFormat]);




    }
  }


  getContacts() {
    // this.contactService.getContacts().subscribe(
    //   data => {
        let result = [{"id":"99F224517781461CB44DDE9DB298367E","firstName":"a","lastName":"a","companyName":"","address":"","email":"a@g.com","primaryContactNumber":"9898989898","altContactNumber":null,"websiteURL":"","deleted":false},{"id":"9780ACC7746A4CAC8A013914CC9FF518","firstName":"as","lastName":"frwef","companyName":"tr","address":"","email":"df@ds.cde","primaryContactNumber":"fwwdqf","altContactNumber":null,"websiteURL":"","deleted":false},{"id":"DCEB2AC83F374A1B89C631A7FF5BE543","firstName":" te","lastName":"te","companyName":"","address":"","email":"rte@ef.dfg","primaryContactNumber":"rt","altContactNumber":null,"websiteURL":"","deleted":false},{"id":"72DD16997D0242E99F0A90A0080D270B","firstName":"William","lastName":"Howell","companyName":"Fleet Solutions","address":"Sugarloaf Township Pennsylvania USA ","email":"william_howell@gmail.com","primaryContactNumber":"+1-87511222556","altContactNumber":"","websiteURL":"www.fleet-solutions.com","deleted":false},{"id":"78292688C0914D149693CB696FF1AEB1","firstName":"William","lastName":"Howell","companyName":"Fleet Solutions","address":"Sugarloaf Township Pennsylvania USA ","email":"william_howell@gmail.com","primaryContactNumber":"+1-87511222558","altContactNumber":"","websiteURL":"www.fleet-solutions.com","deleted":false},{"id":"DF0E93140DAA4E53A5BB9A9002E72544","firstName":"William","lastName":"Howell","companyName":"Fleet Solutions","address":"Sugarloaf Township Pennsylvania USA ","email":"william_howell@gmail.com","primaryContactNumber":"+1-87511222557","altContactNumber":"","websiteURL":"www.fleet-solutions.com","deleted":false},{"id":"F661702AF20E4F12ACED51A9F489CC3C","firstName":"William","lastName":"Howell","companyName":"Fleet Solutions","address":"Sugarloaf Township Pennsylvania USA ","email":"william_howell@gmail.com","primaryContactNumber":"+1-87511222555","altContactNumber":"","websiteURL":"www.fleet-solutions.com","deleted":false}]; //data.data.contacts;
        for (let i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {

          this.contactOptions.push({
            value: result[i].id,
            label: result[i].firstName + " " + result[i].lastName,
            disabled: result[i].deleted
          });
          this.updatedContactOptions.push({
            value: result[i].id,
            label: result[i].firstName + " " + result[i].lastName,
            disabled: result[i].deleted
          });
        }
      // },
      // (err) => {
      //   this.logError(err);
      // });
  }


  clearJobForm() {
    let self = this;
    let format = this.utility.DATEFORMAT_CALENDER[self.dateTimeFormat];
    this.jobFormSubmitted = false;
    this.validAddress = true;
    this.jobForm.get('assignee.user').setValue('user');
    this.assigneeType = 'user';
    this.jobFormData = this.clone(this.jobFormDataOriginal);
    this.initDateTimePicker();
  }





  toggleJobForm(rowData: any, isEdit: boolean) {
    let self = this;
    this.initDateTimePicker();
    this.updatedContactOptions=this.contactOptions;
    for(let g=0;g<this.contactOptions.length;g++){
      if(this.updatedContactOptions[g].disabled){
        this.updatedContactOptions.splice(g,1);
      }
    }
    this.contactOptions=this.updatedContactOptions;
    if (isEdit) {
      this.jobEditId = rowData.id;
      jQuery("span.deletejob:not('.inactive')").removeClass("disabled");
      jQuery('#' + rowData.id).find('span.deletejob').addClass('disabled');
      this.validAddress = true;
      this.jobFrmVisible = true;
      this.setFormData(rowData,this.contactOptions);
      this.jobSubmitButton = this.jobsButtons['UPDATE_JOB'];
      this.jobFrmBtnTitle = this.jobsButtons['CANCEL'];;

    } else {
      if (this.jobFrmVisible) {
        if (this.jobEditId) {
          jQuery('#' + this.jobEditId).find("span.deletejob:not('.inactive')").removeClass('disabled');
        }
        this.jobEditId = '';
        this.jobFrmVisible = false;
        this.jobFrmBtnTitle = this.jobsButtons['CREATE_JOB'];
        this.jobSubmitButton = this.jobsButtons['CREATE_JOB'];

        this.clearJobForm();
      } else {
        this.jobFrmVisible = true;
        this.jobSubmitButton = this.jobsButtons['CREATE_JOB'];;
        this.jobEditId = '';
        this.jobFrmBtnTitle = this.jobsButtons['CANCEL'];;
      }
    }
  }

  logError(error: any) {
    console.log(error);
  }

  handleJobErrors(err: any) {
    let self = this;
    self.errorHtml = '';
    for (let error of err) {
      switch (error.code) {
        case "1032":
          self.jobForm.controls['number'].setErrors({
            "duplicateJobNumber": true
          });
          break;
        default:
          self.isUnknownError = true;
          self.errorHtml += error.message + '</br>';
      }
    };
    if (self.isUnknownError == true) {
      self.jobOperation = "ERROR";
      jQuery('#jobModal').modal('show');
      jQuery('div#jobModal .modal-body').empty().append(self.errorHtml);
    }

  }

}
```

why other array is getting updated?

Comment: Thi is *a lot* of code ! You should learn how to ask a good question by minimizing the amount of code that you post and trim to the exact issue you are facing  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: you are updating the same list

Comment: @Safiyya edited the code

Comment: @ManojP yes updating the same list but in only one array not the other one

Comment: Which is the method you use for the "update"?

Comment: @DiabolicWords  toggleJobForm() in that  i am copying array like this this.contactOptions=this.updatedContactOptions; and in setFormData() i am modifying this.contactOptions[this.contactOptions.length]=this.clone(isDel[0]);
      }

Answer (score 2):

If you want to copy array then use `Object.assign()` method:

```
let arr1 = [1,2,3];
let arr2 = [];
Object.assign(arr2, arr1);
```

If you assigned `arr2 = arr1;` then the reference of `arr1` will also stored in `arra2`. In that case if you change/modified any one array then both array will get change.

### Update

If you want to maintain one original copy you use `const`

```
const arr2 = arr1;  // You can use arr2(it cannot be change)
```

Comment: i tried above method, first i am doing Object.assign(this.updatedContactOptions,this.contactOptions); while resetting i am doing Object.assign(this.contactOptions,this.updatedContactOptions); its not copying in the second case

Comment: If you want to maintain one original copy then why are you not going to constant             const arr2  = arr1      see my updated code

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I don't get your intentions right but this is your toggleJobForm()-method

```
toggleJobForm(rowData: any, isEdit: boolean) {
    let self = this;
    this.initDateTimePicker();
```

You copy this.contactOptions into this.updatedContactOptions

```
  this.updatedContactOptions=this.contactOptions;
```

then you modify this.updatedContactOptions

```
  for(let g=0;g<this.contactOptions.length;g++){
    if(this.updatedContactOptions[g].disabled){
      this.updatedContactOptions.splice(g,1);
    }
  }
```

and then you copy it back into this.contactOptions

```
  this.contactOptions=this.updatedContactOptions;
```

In this method it's quit clear that, whenever you change this.updatedContactOptions, also this.ContactOptions gets changed.

Or do you do this on purpose here?

Comment: I want to maintain one original copy, whenever i am resetting form i need to copy original array to modified array,i want to reset it to the array which i have created in the beginning;